# Spatial overlays: Union between multiline and multipolygon with geopandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I try to overlays (apply union) my multipolygon on the multiline with GeoPandas, but it seems like the GeoPandas `overlay` function work only with (Multi)polygon. Is there any way to make that with multiline and multipolygon with GeoPandas. Here is my code:

```
my_shp = gpd.read_file('my_shp.shp') # it's MultiLines shapefile
shp_buf = my_shp.buffer(5)
# as shp_buf it geoSeries i need to convert it to GeoDataFrame
df_shp_buf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry' : shp_buf})
union_1 = overlay(my_shp, df_shp_buf, how = 'union')
```

And I got this error:

```
TypeError: overlay only takes GeoDataFrames with (multi)polygon geometries
```

Comment: Yeah exactly, that what i want to do, to split lines with polygon attributes

Comment: Can you hard-code some sample geometries using shapely objects?

Comment: Yes, i think i can dp that

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question maybe it will help, but I use fiona and shapely to do that.

First I recover the coords of shapefile and converted i in MultilineString geometry of shapely:

```
import fiona as fn
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString

tab = []
test_shp = fn.open('test_shp.shp')    # the shapefile is a MultiLineString
with fn.open('my_shp.shp') as shp:    # the shapefile is a Multipolygon
    for i in range(0, len(shp)):
        tab.append(next(shp))
    geom = [tab[x]['geometry'] for x in range(0, len(tab))]
    xcoords = [list(geom[x].values())[1] for x in range(0, len(geom))]
    multi = MultiLineString(xcoords)
```

Second time I apply the buffer to get an polygon

```
# buffer
multi_buf = multi.buffer(0.3)
```

Third I make my union

```
#union 
xunion_1 = test.union(multi_buf)
```